# Leer archivo Web.Config en C#

Tags: c#, web.config

Tengo el siguiente `Web.Config`

```
<applicationSettings>
<BPS.Logger.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="LogArchivoRuta" serializeAs="String">
    <value>C:\SetDatosCT\LogDesarrolloLocal.txt</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LogDestino" serializeAs="String">
    <value>ConsolaArchivo</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LogNivel" serializeAs="String">
    <value>3</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LogDbInstancia" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="LogDbBase" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="LogDbLogin" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="LogDbPassword" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>

</BPS.Logger.Properties.Settings>

<BPS.DBC.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="RutaSetDatos" serializeAs="String">
    <value>C:\SetDatosCT\SetDatosDesarrolloLocal.txt</value>
  </setting>
</BPS.DBC.Properties.Settings>
```

Y quiero obtener el valor de la seccion "LogArchivoRuta"

estoy usando el siguiente código

```
var logTB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogArchivoRuta"];
```

Pero me retorna un valor nulo, ambient trate usando

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogArchivoRuta"];
```

y lo mismo, retorna nulo.

Como debo hacerlo para obtener el valor?

Gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<setting name="LogArchivoRuta" serializeAs="String">
    <value>C:\SetDatosCT\LogDesarrolloLocal.txt</value>
  </setting>
```

Cambialo por

```
<setting name="LogArchivoRuta" serializeAs="String" value="C:\SetDatosCT\LogDesarrolloLocal.txt">

  </setting>
```

Recupera la propiedad de la siguiente forma:

```
string Ruta = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogArchivoRuta"].ToString();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @CarlosUmaña pero ahora recibo una excepción
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.this[string].get returned null.

Comment: Podrias revisar un poco este enlace te puede ayudar https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/four-ways-to-read-configuration-setting-in-c-sharp/ , pero debe haber alguna forma de acceder a este tag <BPS.Logger.Properties.Settings> para que luego recuperes el tag que necesitas